# Someone is copying my site in real time

Tags: duplicates

I discovered by accident a website that's copying mine and its content (including GA code) in real time.

Not quite real time, but on a daily basis.

I get how it copied my WP theme (although it looks a bit buggy), but how is it copying my posts along with its images (no hotlinking, though)?

And more importantly, what can I do about it besides the abuse report that I sent to Cloudflare (which they're sending their traffic through)?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use another site's RSS feed to create content on a site. [See this plugin](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-aggregator/).

If you go to Settings > Reading (/wp-admin/options-reading.php) you could try and remove the Full Text from the post feed.

Comment: I set it up now. Let's see how it goes from now on.

Comment: It didn't work. In the RSS feed, the articles are trimmed, but on the site copying mine, it's still a regular post, identical to mine, but his images are uploaded on his server, not hotlinked.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that is downloading through JSON. You could disable that: https://www.greengeeks.com/tutorials/article/disable-rest-api-json-wordpress/

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Could you share the links to the two sites?